# Roslyn Code Analysis: Visual Editing of Rules possible?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis, editorconfig

If I understand correctly, there are two kinds of code analysis available for C# Visual Studio projects:

1. The old legacy analyzers (not available for .NET Core and .NET Standard)
2. Roslyn Code Analyzers

The old legacy analyzers used .ruleset files to configure warnings, errors and suppresions. Visual Studio came with a nice visual interface to edit those ruleset files:
[image: Visual Ruleset Configuration]

The .ruleset file format seems to be deprecated in Roslyn in favour of .editorconfig. Unfortunately, this means the nice visual editor is not available anymore.

Is there any way to get a similar visual interface for .editorconfig files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The C# compiler can use both `.ruleset` and `.editorconfig`.

And Visual Studio 2022 has an editor for `.editorconfig`